# Find remainder of $\sum^{2015}_{n=1}\big(\frac{n+2}{2}\big)^{n+2}$ when divided by $23$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, summation, modular-arithmetic

Find the remainder ($r$) of $\displaystyle\sum^{2015}_{n=1}\left(\frac{n+2}{2}\right)^{n+2}$ when divided by $23$.

**My attempt:**

$\frac{n+2}{2}=1+\frac n 2$

$A=\displaystyle \sum^{2015}_{n=1}\left(\frac{n+2}{2}\right)=2015+\frac 1 2\times \frac{2015\times2016}{2}=505 \times 2015$

We take the mean value as $a$ :

$a=\dfrac A {2015}=505$

So we may write:

$\displaystyle \sum^{2015}_{n=1}\left(\frac{n+2}{2}\right)^{n+2}=\sum^{2015}_{n=1} 505^{n+2}=\frac{505^{2018}-505}{505-1}-505-505^2$

$505≡-1 \mod (23)$

So we have:

$\frac{1 \mod (23) +1 \mod (23)}{-2\mod (23)} +1 \mod (23)-1\mod (23) ≡ -1 \mod (23) ≡22 \mod(23)$

⇒  $r=22$

Or better say:

$r≤ 22$

Can someone find the accurate value?

Notice: A contradiction to be resolved:

Inequality $a^bb^a<\big(\frac{a+b}{2}\big)^{a+b}$ indicates that:

$A=\displaystyle\sum^{2015}_{n=1}n^22^n <B=\displaystyle\sum^{2015}_{n=1}\left(\frac{n+2}{2}\right)^{n+2}$

Therefore one may expect remainders $r_A<r_B$ when A and B are divided by 23, where $r_A=5$ and $r_B=3$.How can this contradiction be explained?

Comment: Why can you just replace the bracket with the mean? How is this expression even an integer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $2017=23\cdot 87+16$, by putting $m=n+2$ and $m=23q+r$, we get:
\begin{align}
\sum^{2015}_{n=1}\Big(\frac{n+2}{2}\Big)^{n+2}
&=-\frac 32+\sum^{2017}_{m=1}\Big(\frac m2\Big)^m\\
&=-\frac 32+\sum_{q=0}^{86}\sum^{22}_{r=1}\Big(\frac{23q+r}{2}\Big)^{23q+r}+\sum^{16}_{r=1}\Big(\frac{23\cdot 87+r}2\Big)^{23\cdot 87+r}\\
&\equiv-\frac 32+\sum_{q=0}^{86}\sum^{22}_{r=1}\Big(\frac r2\Big)^{q+r}+\sum^{16}_{r=1}\Big(\frac r2\Big)^{21+r}\\
&=-\frac 32+\sum^{22}_{r=1}\Big(\frac r2\Big)^r\sum_{q=0}^{86}\Big(\frac r2\Big)^q+\Big(\frac r2\Big)^{21}\sum^{16}_{r=1}\Big(\frac r2\Big)^r\pmod{23}
\end{align}
where I used the congruence $(r/2)^{22}\equiv 1\pmod{23}$.
By applying the formula for geometric sum, we get:
\begin{align}
\sum_{q=0}^{86}\Big(\frac r2\Big)^q
&=
\begin{cases}
87&r=2\\
\frac{(r/2)^{87}-1}{r/2-1}&r\neq 2
\end{cases}\\
&\equiv
\begin{cases}
18&r=2\\
-(\frac r2)^{-1}&r\neq 2
\end{cases}
\pmod{23}
\end{align}
hence by variable changing $r=23-s$ we get:
\begin{align}
\sum^{2015}_{n=1}\Big(\frac{n+2}{2}\Big)^{n+2}
&\equiv-\frac 32+19-\sum^{22}_{r=1}\Big(\frac r2\Big)^{r-1}+\sum^{16}_{r=1}\Big(\frac r2\Big)^{r-1}\\
&=6-\sum^{22}_{r=17}\Big(\frac r2\Big)^{r-1}\\
&=6-\sum^6_{s=1}\Big(\frac{23-s}2\Big)^{23-s-1}\\
&\equiv 6-\sum^6_{s=1}\Big(-\frac s2\Big)^{-s}\\
&\equiv 6-\Bigl(-\frac 12\Bigr)^{-1}-\Bigl(-\frac 22\Bigr)^{-2}-\Bigl(-\frac 32\Bigr)^{-3}-\Bigl(-\frac 42\Bigr)^{-4}-\Bigl(-\frac 52\Bigr)^{-5}-\Bigl(-\frac 62\Bigr)^{-6}\\
&\equiv 6+2-1+\Bigl(\frac 23\Bigr)^3-2^{-4}+\Bigl(\frac 25\Bigr)^5-3^{-6}\\
&\equiv 7+\frac 8{27}-\frac 1{16}+\frac{32}{25^2\cdot 5}-\frac 1{27^2}\\
&\equiv 7+\frac 84-\frac 1{16}+\frac{9}{2^2\cdot 5}-\frac 1{4^2}\\
&\equiv 7+2-\frac 1{16}+\frac 9{20}-\frac 1{16}\\
&\equiv 9-\frac 93-\frac 18\\
&\equiv 9-3-3\\
&\equiv 3\pmod{23}
\end{align}

Comment: Fabio Lucchini, Sorry I can not get your solution.First line is without reasoning. also what is s in last line? may be a more detailed solution helps. Also I want a number in the end.

Comment: @sirous: I added some explanation.

Comment: Fabio, great resolution, thanks.